# First value in DATE minus 30 days SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, max, min

I have bunch of data out of which I'm showing ID, max date and it's corresponding values (user id, type, ...). Then I need to take MAX date for each ID, substract 30 days and show first date and it's corresponding values within this date period.

Example:

```
ID  Date        Name
1   01.05.2018  AAA
1   21.04.2018  CCC
1   05.04.2018  BBB
1   28.03.2018  AAA
```

expected:

```
ID  max_date    max_name previous_date previous_name 
1   01.05.2018  AAA      05.04.2018 BBB
```

I have working solution using subselects, but as I have quite huge WHERE part, refresh takes ages.

SUBSELECT looks like that:
(SELECT MIN(N.name)
    FROM t1 N
    WHERE N.ID = T.ID
        AND (N.date < MAX(T.date) AND N.date >= (MAX(T.date)-30))
        AND (...)) AS PreviousName

How'd you write the select?

I'm using TSQL

Thanks

Comment: paste your code here so we can see if it can get better

Comment: sample data, expected output is always a standard requirement here too :) Otherwise the pseudo code would likely only draw *more* questions

Comment: A pair of APPLY operations might help, but hard to know without seeing what you're doing now.

Comment: ID Date Name
1 01.05.2018 AAA
1 21.04.2018 CCC
1 05.04.2018 BBB
1 28.03.2018 AAA

expected:
ID max_date max_name previous_date previous_name
1 01.05.2018 AAA 05.04.2018 BBB

Comment: and for previous (minus 30 days) I'm using stuff like: 
(SELECT MIN(N.name)
 FROM t1 N
 WHERE N.ID = T.ID
  AND (N.date < MAX(T.date) AND N.date >= (MAX(T.date)-30))
  AND (...)) AS PreviousName

Comment: Rather than post it in a comment, can you edit your original question so that you can add some formatting?

Comment: Also, are your dates stored as actual `date` datatype or as a `varchar` as `dd.mm.yyyy`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can do this with 2 CTEs to build up the dates and names.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/8e644/5)

**MS SQL Server 2017 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (ID int, theDate date, theName varchar(10)) ;

INSERT INTO t1 (ID, theDate, theName)
VALUES
    ( 1,'2018-05-01','AAA' )
  , ( 1,'2018-04-21','CCC' )
  , ( 1,'2018-04-05','BBB' )
  , ( 1,'2018-03-27','AAA' )
  , ( 2,'2018-05-02','AAA' )
  , ( 2,'2018-05-21','CCC' )
  , ( 2,'2018-03-03','BBB' )
  , ( 2,'2018-01-20','AAA' )
;
```

**Main Query**:

```
;WITH cte1 AS (
  SELECT t1.ID, t1.theDate, t1.theName
    , DATEADD(day,-30,t1.theDate) AS dMinus30
    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t1.ID ORDER BY t1.theDate DESC) AS rn
  FROM t1
)
, cte2 AS (
  SELECT c2.ID, c2.theDate, c2.theName
    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY c2.ID ORDER BY c2.theDate) AS rn
    , COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY c2.ID) AS theCount
  FROM cte1
  INNER JOIN cte1 c2 ON cte1.ID = c2.ID
    AND c2.theDate >= cte1.dMinus30
  WHERE cte1.rn = 1
  GROUP BY c2.ID, c2.theDate, c2.theName
)
SELECT cte1.ID, cte1.theDate AS max_date, cte1.theName AS max_name
  , cte2.theDate AS previous_date, cte2.theName AS previous_name 
  , cte2.theCount
FROM cte1 
INNER JOIN cte2 ON cte1.ID = cte2.ID 
  AND cte2.rn=1
WHERE cte1.rn = 1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/8e644/5/0)**:

```
| ID |   max_date | max_name | previous_date | previous_name |
|----|------------|----------|---------------|---------------|
|  1 | 2018-05-01 |      AAA |    2018-04-05 |           BBB |
|  2 | 2018-05-21 |      CCC |    2018-05-02 |           AAA |
```

`cte1` builds the list of `max_date` and `max_name` grouped by the `ID` and then using a `ROW_NUMBER()` window function to sort the groups by the dates to get the most recent date. `cte2` joins back to this list to get all dates within the last 30 days of `cte1`'s max date. Then it does essentially the same thing to get the last date. Then the outer query joins those two results together to get the columns needed while only selecting the most and least recent rows from each respectively.

I'm not sure how well it will scale with your data, but using the CTEs should optimize pretty well.

EDIT: For the additional requirement, I just added in another `COUNT()` window function to `cte2`.

Comment: maybe one more question. can I add also new column to see how many IDs we have within this 30 days. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would do:

```
select id,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then date end) as max_date,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then name end) as max_name,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then date end) as prev_date,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then name end) as prev_name,
from (select e.*, row_number() over (partition by id order by date desc) as seqnum
      from example e
     ) e
group by id;
```

Comment: That has a much cleaner execution plan than mine, but it doesn't include the "min date within 30 days of max" requirement. Can this be modified to pick only the latest 30 days of an ID? Maybe modify the subselect and a `WHERE` clause. I like this approach.